# Define a public Dictionary

Tags: vba

I write simple code to define a public dictionary in VBA but It raised error:

> "Object Variable or with block variable not set.".

**in module1:**

```
Option Explicit

Public a As Scripting.Dictionary

Sub main()
    Set a = New Scripting.Dictionary  
    a.Add 1, "a"
End Sub
```

**in sheet1:**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Debug.Print a.Items(0)
End Sub
```

It seems that "a" dictionary is not defined as public and it is not accessible. What should I do to have access to "a" dictionary in any sheets and modules and subroutines?

Answer (score 0):

`a` is accessible, just not initialized until after you've called `main` -- technically, [the variable is dissociated from any object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/nothing-keyword). A simple hack would be:

```
Public a As New Scripting.Dictionary
```

but then it will not have any values, and any attempt to retrieve a value will cause an error.

Alternatively, you could make the dictionary non-public, and expose it through a function that would initialize the dictionary if needed:

```
Dim a As Scripting.Dictionary

Public Function A1() As Scripting.Dictionary
    If a Is Nothing Then
        Set a = New Scripting.Dictionary
        a(1) = "a"
    End If
    Set A1 = a
End Function
```

which you could then call:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Debug.Print A1(1)
End Sub
```